# Different logo on each categories

Tags: php, wordpress, function, categories

I want to change a different logo for a category and it's articles. The category is https://afdigitale.it/category/af-gaming/ and logo: `AF-Gaming.png`.
I use in `functions.php` this code but it does not work:

```
<?php
    if (is_category ('6933')) {?>
        <img src = "https://afdigitale.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/AF-Gaming.png" />
    <? Php
    }
    else { ?>
        <img src="https://afdigitale.it/wp-content/uploads/AF-Digitale-logo.png" />
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Take a peek at that `<? Php` bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found php syntax error in your code in line 4.

Heres the correct code:

```
<?php
if (is_category ('6933')) {?>
<img src = "https://afdigitale.it/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/AF-Gaming.png">
<?php
}
else { ?>
<img src="https://afdigitale.it/wp-content/uploads/AF-Digitale-logo.png">
<?php
}
?>
```

You can check this code with functions.php but for actual logo replace you may need to use this code in header.php or any other file where original code for logo is written.

Comment: Hi Achyutam, thanks for your answer. The code is ok!

Comment: Hi  Achyutam, I want to change a different background color of header for a category. I use in functions.php this code but it does not work:

<?php
if (in_category ('6933')) {?>
<style="background-color:black">
<?php
}
elseif (is_category ('6933')) {?>
<style="background-color:black">
<?php
}
?>

Comment: Hi mic, Try with the following code.

Lets assume div having id="header" is your header. It'll be different for your actual code. 

<div id="header" style="background-color:<?php echo in_category('6933') ? 'black' : 'red';  ?>">Hello World</div>

Again you need to add this code in your header tag most probably in header.php not functions.php

Comment: Hello Achyutam, thanks for your reply. I have add this code: add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_css_head' );
function add_css_head() {
    if ( in_category('6933')) {?>
        <style type="text/css">.header-middle.herald-header-wraper.hidden-xs.hidden-sm {background-color:#000;}</style>
        <?php
    }
if ( in_category('6933')) {?>
        <style type="text/css">.header-top.hidden-xs.hidden-sm {background-color:#1f1e23;}</style>
<style type="text/css">.header-top a {color: #fff;}</style>
        <?php
    }
}